# How does the ExpressionEngine software registration screen and banner work?

Tags: registration, license

I've just updated an old EE 2.5.5 site to run EE 2.9.0.

The site runs successfully after the update however in the control panel I am now seeing the Software Registration banner.

I've followed the link to the software registration page which asks for the license holder email and the license number which I have entered and submitted but the banner will not go away.

Is the "license holder email" the EllisLab account email address? (that is the one I have entered)

Also, I am using NSM Config Bootstrap which *may*(?) have something to do with this but I am not sure.

In the `system/expressionengine/config/config.php` file, I do see the lines for `$config['license_number']` and `$config['license_contact']` having been added and updated with the correct values that I have entered.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.